# SQL IF NOT EXISTS - how to return/interpret when it does exist

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I have an IF NOT EXISTS statement.  IF it doesn't exist an INSERT statement follows.  IF EXISTS I need to understand what is/can be returned so that I can interpret it with PHP.

so:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE lname='SMITH')
INSERT INTO users (lname='SMITH')
```

I thought that the negative would return no result so could use a standard

```
if ($result){echo "record added";}
else {echo "duplicate - no record added";}
```

But that's not what's happening and I'm not sure how to achieve what I need - any suggestions?

Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: How is `$result` being defined?  SQL is still going to generate an 'I did something' object, although I'm not entirely sure what that looks like in PHP.  To my knowledge, if no row is inserted, you'll get a (fairly) standard code `100`; however, I'm not sure what the way you've written the SQL is going to do to that.  I'd prefer re-writing it into a form which will always execute the `INSERT`, but it won't always have a row to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases `$result` would return the response for a successfully run command and nothing more.  `INSERT` doesn't yield any rows, and neither does an `IF` statement that doesn't have a matching condition.

You can use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` if you want to retrieve the inserted ID, and then you can check if `$result` has returned a row.

Comment: I tried `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY` first but unfortunately it returns a result regardless - it's just the LAST result so this turns out to always be affirmative.  Thank you for the input, PinnyM!

Comment: Right, but the idea was to perform the `SELECT` as part of the `IF NOT EXISTS` body, similar to @nonnb's solution

Comment: You're right, PinnyM...I can just use `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` before `END` and leave off the `ELSE` entirely.  Better solution.  Cheers!

Comment: It's also necessary to rewrite the php a bit: instead of `if ($result)` it needs to be `if (mssql_fetch_array($result))`  (this was required for both solutions)

Answer (score 1):

You might try something like:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM users WHERE lname='SMITH')
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users (lname) VALUES('SMITH')
    SELECT 1
  END
ELSE
  SELECT 0
```

And check the returned scalar = 0 or 1 ?

Comment: I've ended up using a variation of what you've proposed:  `...SELECT 1 AS response END ELSE SELECT NULL AS response` which works...will have to do some more research on this when I have more time.  Thanks for the response, nonnb!